# One Ring to rule them all

Tags: visual

Gollum is focused on his new ring. There is magic inside, he can feel it. A beautiful black ring with some golden symbols. He wants to know the power of this jewel but he can't wait to go back home to use an elvish dictionary.

Can you help him find out ?

[image]

HINT :

> [Elvish language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarati)

Comment: Nice visuals. It seems that the "inner" text appears to be in the lower 2/3 of the ring - is this correct/important ?

Comment: @BmyG textuest It is supposed to be at the level as the outter text

Comment: Jewel? I don't see a jewel.

Comment: @corsiKa - a jewel can just mean a treasured person/item. It does not need to be a literal jewel, which I assume is the case here.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The power of the ring is ...

> [image: Faux Elvish inscriptions overlaid]
>
>  The word can be seen in capital Latin letters when one rotates one of the partial inscriptions by 180° around the "finger" axis of the ring and overlays the two parts. The red parts come from the inscription on the inside of the ring  and the black parts are the inscription on the outside of the ring.

The reference to the Elvish script is ...

> ... a red herring.

Comment: You say the hint was a red herring. So are hints that _aren't_ hints allowed? I guess they would be, just curious if it was ever brought up on meta.

Comment: Probably it is not red herring, but refers to Boustrophedon https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boustrophedon

Comment: Well, I thought it was a red herring; maybe I'm wrong. I imagined the ring as being made from two concentric transparent halves which were then rotated to line up. The mirrored part on the inside would then been seen as unmirrored when seen from outside.

Comment: Wait, so this ring has the power of the previous one without the evil (basically)?

Comment: The leap from Tolkein's elvish language to Boustrophedon is pretty outrageous, per the linked Wiki page: "It has been described as a script that looks like a "mixture of Hebrew, Greek, and Pitman's shorthand."[3] Unfortunately, there are no clues as to what writing systems influenced Tolkien's scripts. This also might mean that his invented scripts found their origins from his mind alone." - the Wiki page proffered as a hint, at least, does nothing to direct the reader in that vein.

Comment: ... that's not to say I perforce object to a red herring, I'm just saying I don't think it can be argued that it is, in fact, a red herring.

Comment: It was a misleading hint. I was trying to make solvers think about something more complicated than just common english ;)

Comment: @Lordofdark: Well, you succeeded.  My first thought was to try overlaying the 2 inscriptions.  But before giving it a shot, I read the hint, and - believing it to be true - did not make any further attempt at the puzzle.  So I guess Insane has a point there.  But a nice puzzle, nevertheless.